# Selenium Test doesn't run

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, netbeans-8

I'm writing a program for Booth's Multiplication as a JAVA Web Application in Netbeans 8.2. I am using selenium-server-standalone-2.50.1.jar and Firefox 46.

When I write my code and run it, it just opens the page but no tests happen. Please help.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * 
 */

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class booth {
    private WebElement element, element1;
    public String str;

    public void Mul_Positive(){
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://localhost:8080/BoothsMul/index.html");
        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='t1']"));
        element.sendKeys("2");
        str = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='t1']")).getText();

        System.out.println(str);

        element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='t2']"));
        element1.sendKeys("5");
        str = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='t2']")).getText();

        System.out.println(str);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='submit']")).click();
        driver.quit();
    }

    public void Mul_Negative(){
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://localhost:8080/BoothsMul/index.html");
        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='t1']"));
        element.sendKeys("c");
        str = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='t1']")).getText();

        System.out.println(str);

        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='t2']"));
        element.sendKeys("5");
        str = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='t2']")).getText();

        System.out.println(str);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='submit']")).click();
        driver.quit();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        booth b = new booth();

        b.Mul_Positive();
        b.Mul_Negative();

    }
}
```

My index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <body>

        <form name='f1' action='http://localhost:8080/BoothsMul/Boothmul' method='get'>
First No. <input type='text' name='t1'><br>
Second No. <input type='text' name='t2'><br>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are your selenium, Java version?

Comment: @kushal Selenium 2.50.1 Java 1.8 Firefox 46

Comment: If you're using Java 8 then selenium version should be 3.0 or higher also, you'll need to make use of geckodriver to run firefox

Comment: Else, you need to downgrade to Java 1.7

Comment: Okay, have you resolved the issue?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

If you're using `selenium 3.0.1` or higher then JAVA version should be 1.8 also, you'll need to make use of `geckodriver` to run `Firefox`. (Make sure you are using latest versions of all the required component in this case)

Else, you need to upgrade your Selenium Version to `3.0 or higher`.

Comment: Its the other way round, if you are using selenium version > 3.0 then java version should be minimum 8 .... its not like if you are using java version 8 old jar wouldn't work... here the issue is compatibility of `Selenium Version` and `FF version`.